# True meaning of はい、どうぞ

Tags: meaning

In the nhk course for Japanese, I came across the following lines:

> さくらさん。はい、どうぞ。

which means

> Sakura. This is for you.

But

> どうぞ

means "Please". Then how can

> はい、どうぞ

mean "This is for you"?

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/どうぞ

Comment: If you look at a Japanese dictionary you'll see both of the meanings you mentioned spelled out. It's as simple as that; it has multiple meanings.

Comment: The どうぞ that is translatable to "please" and the どうぞ translatable to "This is for you." are not semantically different, at least not as different as "please" and "This is for you." are. The latter "どうぞ" does mean "please" (it has the same meaning as in "どうぞ受け取ってください/Please take it."), to the extent  that "どうぞ" can be said to mean "please" generally,  but it's not what English-speaking people would normally say in the given situation. So whoever translated it had to came up with some expression that sounds more natural and have a similar communicative purpose, and that was "This is for you."

Answer (score 5):

It not so much that "どうぞ" has differently defined meanings as that it doesn't have a "meaning" in and of itself. It is an expression used when inviting, encouraging, permitting or asking someone to do something. (I agree it works somewhat like "please".)

What, therefore, that something that you are inviting, etc. the addressee to do by its utterance is wholly dependent on the context.

For example, if you say "どうぞ" to someone standing by an unoccupied chair, gesturing toward it, by that you are inviting them to sit in it. This "どうぞ" may be translated as "Take your seat."

Or picture two people rushing to a bus and reaching the door at the same time, almost bumping into each other. One might say to the other "お先にどうぞ" or just "どうぞ". This is a courteous way of telling them to go on first. A fitting translation here may be "After you."

Or imagine, lastly, that I got you are a present and I'm holding it out to you, so that I can give it to you. As an encouragement for you to take it, I may accompany this with "はい、どうぞ", or, as I might as well say in English to accomplish the same goal, "This is for you."

The use of all three "どうぞ"s above is the same. But since their contexts and therefore their pragmatic meanings differ greatly, translations for these instances of the same word may also differ to the same extent.

Comment: Those different scenarios do have separate listed entries though. https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%9E

Comment: Do they? To me they all seem to fall under the second entry: ②
相手の動作を促したり，物を勧めたりするときに用いる語。

Comment: The two meanings mentioned in the question, はいどうず meaning "here you are" is #3, at least to my reading of it, and どうぞ meaning "please" as just a polite expression when making a request is #1. In any case, it's not merely a matter of translation, there are multiple entries for the word in monolingual dictionaries.

Comment: Oh, you meant those in the question. Well, as for the bare "どうぞ" which the OP thinks means "please", you don't know it's for making a polite request rather than for invitation, since there's no context given. It could be a "どうぞ/please" as in, say, "どうぞお座りください/Please sit down," but then how do you propose to say that it's a polite request but not a polite invitation?

Comment: And if we go by the dictionary's definitions, though it's a bit hard to say, I think the the "はい、どうぞ" in the question is closer to #2 than #3, since, I assume, there was no request or wish on the receiver's part before the present-giving. But then again maybe there was such a request and then it was left out. We don't know.

Comment: And that's the point of it all. Whether it falls under some second or third definition some lexicographer devised, whether there in fact was a prior request for the present or not, the speaker's intention, or meaning, behind the words "はい、どうぞ" -- encouragement, invitation, recommendation or the granting of a wish, whatever it is -- is clear as a bell. That's because "どうぞ" has a fundamental use we universally recognize. We work out a context-specific meaning for each instance of the word based on this, and certain of us try to assign much less specific categories of meaning to the word itself.

Comment: But do they do that in an entirely, or adequately, true and rational manner? Or could the boundaries they draw be arbitrary? The dictionary you linked to groups "相手の動作を促す" and "物を勧める" together in one definition but not "相手の依頼や希望をかなえる", when the first two are, it seems to me, as similar (or as different) to each other as they are to the third.

Comment: If they are so into separatism (though inconsistently so, apparently), why not also split "依頼をかなえる" and "希望をかなえる" into two, for good measure? By the way, the entry for どうぞ in 広辞苑 put "依頼・勧誘・祈願の意" into the same sub-entry and "承諾の意" into a separate one. Hmm... I don't know about them, but I prefer a more monistic approach here. And finally, if it's not merely a matter of translation, I'd say dictionaries shouldn't be so remiss in their work as to not include "take your seat", "after you," "this is for you", and other tens of thousands of possible "definitions" in their entries for "どうぞ".

Comment: Look, I'm not trying to start a thing here, but it sounded like your answer was refuting the comment I left on the question, and making a claim that the word actually has no meaning in and of itself. So I linked to the source I was referring to. I'm not claiming to be a better source of Japanese than a dictionary written by native speakers for native speakers, so I'm not going to try to write my own definitions for words.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded confrontational. I wasn't challenging you to a thing or anything. I was just replying to a comment to my post with my own thoughts.

Comment: I understand, no apology necessary. My interpretation of your answer was unnecessarily defensive in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are waiting for a drink at Pub, a bartender might say.

> はい、どうぞ。ボンベイ・サファイアのロックです。

Here you go. This is your Bombay Sapphire on the rocks. In this case, a bartender serves your drink in front of you.

If you came across someone else just in front of a cashier register and you want to give him first turn, you might say

> お先にどうぞ。

Αfter you.

Both case,  どうぞ works as a recommendation. And, in most case, she does.

Answer (score 0):

どうぞ can be translated as "Here you are," "This is for you."

はい can be translated as "Here you are," "This is for you" in some contexts.

はい、どうぞ can be translated as "Here you are," "This is for you." This is a longer version.

This is not quite surprise.

For example,

"Thanks" expresses the gratitude to the listener. The shorter version.

"You" means the second person, the listener.

"Thank you" still means the gratitude to the listener. The longer version.